# Generating multiple xlsx-output in R

Tags: r, excel, matrix, export

I have two questions to the "xlsx"-package in R:

(1.) I created several matrices in R and now I want to export each matrix in a separate sheet, but all sheets should be in the same "xlsx"-file. I tried to use the "xlsx"-package, however I can't find out how to generate multiple output.

So far I used this to generate several "xlsx"-sheets:

```
    write.xlsx2(matrix1, "File_Name_Matrix_1.xls", row.names=F)
    write.xlsx2(matrix2, "File_Name_Matrix_2.xls", row.names=F)
```

(2.) Is it possible to give the sheets the same name as my matrices in R have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `XLConnect`:

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("XLConnectExample1.xlsx", create = TRUE)

tables <- list("Name_Matrix_1","Name_Matrix_2")
invisible(lapply(tables,function(tab_name){
   createSheet(wb, name = tab_name)
   writeWorksheet(wb, get(tab_name), sheet = tab_name)
}))
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

### EDIT:

The code above:

- Create a workbook (an xlsx file)
- loop over the names of the matrices, For each matrix name , create a sheet with the same name, and save the matrix (having this name) in the already created workbook
- Finally it saves workbook.

Comment: But it is necessary to create all files separately before as I did it above? I cannot use the matrices from R directly to generate a "multi-sheet" xlsx-file?

Comment: E.g. I have the matrices m1<-matrix(0,4,2) and m2<-matrix(1,10,4). As I understand your code I first have to export each matrix with write.xlsx(...) and then I can use your code to create a multi-file sheet. Is this right?

Comment: @jeffrey No. ( I don't understand you gain). I add a code explanation.